# New Graphite installation doesn't render fonts in graphs (except Courier)

Tags: graphite, centos6.5

I've been studying this problem for a couple of days now without success ...

I've configured and deployed Graphite (with carbon and whisper) using the Puppet Graphite module on a CentOS 6.5 server. The webapp will only render text in the graphs if I select Courier as the font face.

I know that Graphite uses cairo to render the PNG graphs, and that relies on freetype or the fontconfig library. All of those are installed.

Other people have solved this problem by installing the "bitmap-fonts" package. The package installed on my server is "bitmaps-fonts-compat" which one would hope is compatible with "bitmap-fonts".

The version of cairo provided in the RedHat repos is 1.8 (a few revisions old).

Comment: What messages do you see in the graphite webapp's logs when you try to render a font other than courier?

Comment: rendering.log records no errors: just "Rendered PNG in 0.08... seconds"

Comment: What's the output of fc-list?

Comment: ]$ fc-list
MiscFixed:style=Regular
Utopia:style=Bold Italic
Console:style=Regular
LucidaTypewriter:style=Sans Bold
Utopia:style=Bold
Bitstream Charter:style=Bold Italic
Cursor:style=Regular
Bitstream Charter:style=Regular
Courier 10 Pitch:style=Bold Italic
Bitstream Charter:style=Italic
MiscFixed:style=SemiCondensed
LucidaTypewriter:style=Sans
MiscFixed:style=Bold
Courier 10 Pitch:style=Italic
Utopia:style=Italic
Courier 10 Pitch:style=Regular
Fangsong ti:style=Regular
Courier 10 Pitch:style=Bold
MiscFixed:style=Bold SemiCondensed
Fixed:style=Regular
Utopia:style=Regular
Bitstream Charter ...

Comment: And all of those are available in Graphite, but only text in Courier is visible?

Comment: The Graphite UI offers font faces Sans, Times, and Helvetica, besides Courier. The other three render nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. To workaround this, change `fontname` from `Sans` to `LucidaTypewriter` (or any other from fc-list) in `graphite/render/glyph.py` on my server the full path is: `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/graphite/render/glyph.py`

diff:

```
64c64
<   fontname='LucidaTypewriter',
---
>   fontname='Sans',
```

and restart wsgi server.

Comment: Nice! Now, in the file, it says "This gets overriden by graphTemplates.conf" which on my system is not found in the /opt/graphite tree. (That's where I found glyph.py.) So it looks in theory like I might solve the problem by properly creating a graphTemplates.conf file and override the font name there. That missing conf file might be key.

Comment: My graphite installation is in /opt/graphite. In /opt/graphite/conf there's a graphTemplates.conf.example file, but not graphTemplates.conf. Using puppet I installed a graphTemplates.conf in /opt/graphite/conf replacing "Sans" with "LucidaTypewriter" and got my default fonts back.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue on Fedora 21 and fixed it by installing `dejavu-sans-fonts` & `dejavu-serif-fonts` (without `bitmaps-fonts-compat`).